# Automate patches for ArgoCD Application pointing to external sources

Tags: kubernetes, devops, argocd

So my problem here is that i have a ArgoCD Application that points to a external repo URL like so

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: emissary
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: emissary
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: admin
  sources:
  - repoURL: 'ambassador' #i know it is wrong, but i have the right source in my real yaml
    targetRevision: 8.9.1
    chart: emissary-ingress
```

This application deploys a helm chart in which a resource of `Kind: Service` is defined that has

```yaml
spec:
  ports:
  - name: name
    port: 8080
  ...
```

Now what i'd like to achieve is to be able to add another port to the array of ports in an automated way. For now the process consists in me uploading the Application manifest to gitlab and then wait for argoCD to create all the things defined in the Helm chart. After that i manually execute

```
kubectl patch svc svc-name --patch-file patch.yaml
kubectl rollout restart deployment deployment-name
```

But ideally this process needs to be automated too and i have no clue on how to do it. Unfortunately the spec parameter of the Service resource is not a parameter that could be set or a value. If any wants to take a look at my specific case i'll leave the [repository link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/datawire/emissary-ingress/8.9.1)
I'll happily discuss every solution that will be proposed since i'm kinda new to the ops world and the more i can learn the better

EDIT: i pasted the wrong bit of code

Comment: you should look into Kustomize w/ the helm chart inflator

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt way to patch ArgoCD applications in this manner. You will have to create the svc file with the patch already applied to it, push the file to a Git repo, then point the ArgoCD application path to this svc file for ArgoCD to be able to properly deploy it. If you use something like Jenkins that runs a build every time a commit is pushed, you could consider adding your patch file automatically at build time, then creating a tag from that patched version. You could then reference this tag in ArgoCD instead of directly referencing a branch.